# dgrid ondemand grid not filling with memory store

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I'm trying to fill my dgrid onDemand Grid with a memory store, but the grid wont populate with the data.  I'm making an xhr.get call and I've verified the data is being returned.  This is what I have:

```
 ......     
 var grid;

 function TicketUnMarkedSet(GridData) {//this function is called back after xhr.get and the parameter GridData is populated
          var gridStore = new Memory({ data: GridData });//this store seems to be ok
          grid = new OnDemandGrid({
              showHeader: true,
              store:gridStore
          }, "gridDiv");
          grid.startup(); 
          grid.refresh();
      }

<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 999;">
          <div id="tpStationData" data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title:'Open Tickets', closable:false,  open:false">
              <div id="gridTabDiv" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" style="width: 100%;
                  height: 100%; overflow: auto;" title="Data">
                  <div id="gridDiv">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Any idea why this grid would be empty?  Thanks

Comment: I added columns to the grid as below -- the columns do appear, but the data does not.  When I debug I can look at the grid and see that it does have a data store.

'code'function TicketUnMarkedSet(GridData) {
              var gridStore = new Memory({ data: GridData });
              grid = new OnDemandGrid({
                  showHeader: true,
                  store: gridStore,
                  columns: {
                  ID: "ID",
                  Ticket: "Ticket",
                  Street: "Address",
                  DateRcvd: "DateRcvd"
              }
      
.....
          'code'

Comment: Check your json data in GridData.  It might have a syntax error. Add to the post if you can.

Comment: I verified the JSON on JSONLint -- a sample
`{"TicketUnMarkedGetResult":[{"Company":"E W HARMON","DateRcvd":"\/Date(1387311540000-0800)\/","DaysToWork":-202,"ID":9972,"OldTicket":"A30140156","Priority":"NORM","Street":" EL PRADO RD","Ticket":"A30730511","Type":"UPDT","WorkDate":"\/Date(1387311540000-0800)\/","ptCenterX":-13099875.6316766,"ptCenterY":4024215.96028757}]}`

Answer (score 0):

Check gridStore Memory object to see if valid data exists:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/Memory.html

I think you should add lower-case 'id:1' to your JSON data and increment this value by 1 for each record.

```
require(["dojo/store/Memory"], function(Memory){
    var someData = [
        {id:1, name:"One"},
        {id:2, name:"Two"}
    ];
    store = new Memory({data: someData});

    store.get(1) -> Returns the object with an id of 1

    store.query({name:"One"}) // Returns query results from the array that match the given query

    store.query(function(object){
        return object.id > 1;
    }) // Pass a function to do more complex querying

    store.query({name:"One"}, {sort: [{attribute: "id"}]}) // Returns query results and sort by id

    store.put({id:3, name:"Three"}); // store the object with the given identity

    store.remove(3); // delete the object
});
```

Make your JSON data input in GridData look like someData in the above example.

Maybe change:

```
var gridStore = new Memory({ data: GridData });
```

to

```
var gridStore = new Memory({ data: GridData.TicketUnMarkedGetResult });
```

Then add dataStore (ObjectStore):

```
dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: gridStore });
```

add dataStore to your grid:

```
grid = new DataGrid({
        store: dataStore,
```

Hopefully, this will help you out..
I found this info on the demo page for data grids:

In this example from this page:  http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/datagrid/

Dojo grid demo:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/datagrid/demo/datagrid.php

JSON data for the grid:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/datagrid/demo/hof-batting.json

Code for this demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo: dojox/grid/DataGrid</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.5/dojo/resources/dojo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.5/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../resources/style/demo.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <h1>Demo: dojox/grid/DataGrid</h1>

    <br/>
    <div id="grid"></div>

    <!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.5/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
        var grid, store, dataStore;
        require([
            "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
            "dojo/store/Memory",
            "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
            "dojo/request",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(DataGrid, Memory, ObjectStore, request){
            request.get("all-batting.json", {
                handleAs: "json"
            }).then(function(data){
                store = new Memory({ data: data.items });
                dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: store });

                grid = new DataGrid({
                    store: dataStore,
                    query: { id: "*" },
                    structure: [
                        {
                            noscroll: true,
                            defaultCell: { width: "84px" },
                            cells: [
                                { name: "First Name", field: "first" },
                                { name: "Last Name", field: "last" }
                            ]
                        },{
                            defaultCell: { width: "60px" },
                            cells: [
                                [
                                    { name: "Bats", field: "bats", width: "70px", rowSpan: 2 },
                                    { name: "Throws", field: "throws", width: "70px", rowSpan: 2 },
                                    { name: "G", field: "totalG" },
                                    { name: "AB", field: "totalAB" },
                                    { name: "R", field: "totalR" },
                                    { name: "RBI", field: "totalRBI" },
                                    { name: "BB", field: "totalBB" },
                                    { name: "K", field: "totalK" }
                                ],[
                                    { name: "Games as Batter", field: "totalGAB", colSpan: 2 },
                                    { name: "H", field: "totalH" },
                                    { name: "2B", field: "total2B" },
                                    { name: "3B", field: "total3B" },
                                    { name: "HR", field: "totalHR" }
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, "grid");

                // since we created this grid programmatically, call startup to render it
                grid.startup();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this approach but still didnt work.  One of the tutorials had a grid.on("dgrid-error"), which I used, but the grid doesnt seem to be throwing an error.  I'm really stumped

Comment: This is a real stab in the dark...But, what about changing your json data element from 'TicketUnMarkedGetResult' to 'items'??

Comment: Edited my post above to check the Memory Object. Check out the top of my post.

Comment: I tried querying the store and nothing was returned.  Looks like there is something wrong with the store.  The JSON is valid, but I know from past experience that dojo doesnt like the date format that is returned back from SQL Server "DateRcvd":"\/Date(1387311540000-0800)\/".  Maybe this is the problem --

Comment: I would remove {"TicketUnMarkedGetResult": from your JSON and add 'id:<rec #> to each record.  Maybe define all date fields as strings until you get data to display properly. Possibly rename ID field to REC_ID??

Answer (score 0):

As per the tutorial (See link [here](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/grids_and_stores/) for details), it has **columns** included for the data grid, which has been excluded in your code. 
Maybe that is the issue.

```
    // Create an instance of OnDemandGrid referencing the store
    var grid = new OnDemandGrid({
        store: store,
        columns: {
            first: "First Name",
            last: "Last Name",
            totalG: "Games Played"
        }
    }, "grid");

    grid.startup();
```

Also if the above changes does not work you could create a local data store ( for testing purpose only) as below. It will help you to narrow the problem.

```
function TicketUnMarkedSet(GridData) {//this function is called back after xhr.get and the parameter GridData is populated

    var testdata = [
                     { id:1, first: "Bob", last: "Barker", age: 89 },
                     { id:2, first: "Vanna", last: "White", age: 55 },
                     { id:3, first: "Pat", last: "Sajak", age: 65 }
    ];

    var gridStore = new Memory({ data: testdata });

    // Create an instance of OnDemandGrid referencing the store
    var grid = new OnDemandGrid({
        store: gridStore ,
        columns: {
            first: "First Name",
            last: "Last Name",
            age: "Age"
        }
    }, "gridDiv");
    grid.startup();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the format of my json.  When I get it back from my service it looks like this:

```
 [{"Company":"E W HARMON","DateRcvd":"\/Date(1387311540000-0800)\/","DaysToWork":-203,"ID":9972,"OldTicket":"A30140156","Priority":"NORM","Street":" EL PRADO RD","Ticket":"A30730511","Type":"UPDT","WorkDate":"\/Date(1387311540000-0800)\/","ptCenterX":-13099875.6316766,"ptCenterY":4024215.96028757},{"Company":"E W HARMON","DateRcvd":"\/Date(1389731340000-0800)\/","DaysToWork":-175,"ID":10263,"OldTicket":"A30140156","Priority":"NORM","Street":" EL PRADO RD","Ticket":"A30730511","Type":"UPDT","WorkDate":"\/Date(1389731340000-0800)\/","ptCenterX":-13099875.6316766,"ptCenterY":4024215.96028757}]
```

and it doesn't work with my dgrid.  If I run it through the validator at http://jsonlint.com/ it says the data is valid json, but changes it to:

```
[
{
    "Company": "E W HARMON",
    "DateRcvd": "/Date(1387311540000-0800)/",
    "DaysToWork": -203,
    "ID": 9972,
    "OldTicket": "A30140156",
    "Priority": "NORM",
    "Street": " EL PRADO RD",
    "Ticket": "A30730511",
    "Type": "UPDT",
    "WorkDate": "/Date(1387311540000-0800)/",
    "ptCenterX": -13099875.6316766,
    "ptCenterY": 4024215.96028757
},
{
    "Company": "E W HARMON",
    "DateRcvd": "/Date(1389731340000-0800)/",
    "DaysToWork": -175,
    "ID": 10263,
    "OldTicket": "A30140156",
    "Priority": "NORM",
    "Street": " EL PRADO RD",
    "Ticket": "A30730511",
    "Type": "UPDT",
    "WorkDate": "/Date(1389731340000-0800)/",
    "ptCenterX": -13099875.6316766,
    "ptCenterY": 4024215.96028757
}]
```

which works with grid -- I just need to find a way to make this transformation

Comment: Sound like you're almost there..http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp  Maybe try var gridObj = JSON.parse(gridData); then plug gridObj into your data store??

Comment: JSON.parse() fails, I think because it is already an array of objects.  I'm trying to convert to string, add carriage returns after each object, then re-parse.
 var STicketData = JSON.stringify(result, null, "\r");
 var OTicketData = JSON.parse(STicketData).  But getting no luck with this